# mingw: Invalid conversion from lambda to function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, lambda, mingw

Trying to supply a lambda as a function pointer to a Win32 API call fails when compiling using mingw 5.3.0, although it compiles fine when using MSVC (of Visual Studio 2013).

MCVE:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool parameterData;

    EnumWindows([](HWND windowHandle, LPARAM parameter) -> BOOL {
        return 1;
    }, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&parameterData));
}
```

GCC throws the following error message, which I can't wrap my head around:

```
error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'main(int, char**)::<lambda(HWND, LPARAM)>' to 'WNDENUMPROC {aka int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(HWND__*, long int)}' [-fpermissive]
  }, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&parameterData));
                                             ^
note: candidate is: main(int, char**)::<lambda(HWND, LPARAM)>::operator BOOL (*)(HWND, LPARAM)() const <near match>
  EnumWindows([](HWND windowHandle, LPARAM parameter) -> BOOL {
                                                         ^
note:   no known conversion from 'BOOL (*)(HWND, LPARAM) {aka int (*)(HWND__*, long int)}' to 'WNDENUMPROC {aka int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(HWND__*, long int)}'
In file included from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:72:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
note:   initializing argument 1 of 'WINBOOL EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC, LPARAM)'
   WINUSERAPI WINBOOL WINAPI EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc,LPARAM lParam);
```

What is it exactly that GCC does not like? What needs to be changed in order to use the lambda as first parameter to `EnumWindows`?

Comment: The problem seems to be the conversion of the stateless lambda... does you compiler support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EnumWindows` expects a callback with the `stdcall` calling convention. GCC has no support for converting stateless lambdas into `stdcall` function pointers, and there's no way that I'm aware of to mark the lambda as such. MSVC, however, provides conversions to function pointers with a variety of calling conventions.

Unfortunately, you're going to have to use a separate function or use MSVC:

```
BOOL CALLBACK callback(HWND windowHandle, LPARAM parameter) { ... }
...
EnumWindows(callback, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&parameterData));
```

Comment: Do you know if anything has changed since you posted this?

Comment: @Paul, I'm unsure, sorry. It's at least easy enough to test for support if the compiler's set up.

Answer (score 0):

```
EnumWindows([](HWND windowHandle, LPARAM parameter) -> BOOL __attribute__((__stdcall__)) {
    return 1;
```